# Find div inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a Page, inherited by a MasterPage. In this page I have two iframes- FrameProcessGrid & FrameProjectQuickView.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div id="CenterPanel" class="CenterPanel">
        <iframe id="FrameProcessGrid" runat="server" src="ProjectList.aspx" height="99%" width="99%" style="margin:0px auto;"></iframe>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="ContentRight" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderRight" runat="server">
    <div class="RightPanel">
        <iframe id="FrameProjectQuickView" runat="server" src="QuickView.aspx" height="99%" width="99%" style="margin:0px auto;"></iframe>
    </div>
        <div id="HiddenQuickView">
            <input id="ShowQuickViewBtn" type="button" value="<" />
        </div>
</asp:Content>`
```

Now when I fire a clientclick event from 1st iframe - `id=FrameProcessGrid` ,it return NULL OR UNDEFINED.

I need to PRINT some TEXT in DIV i.e `iframe FrameProjectQuickView . div.innerHTML`

How could I do it ?

Comment: does your iframe elements come from the same server? if not, you won'r be able to make changes inside iframe

Comment: It is from the same. I am unable to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$('#iframeID').contents().find('#yourdivID');
```

Comment: It is returning OBJECT but when I use .innerHTML when below code is given. It returns undefined.

`<div id="DivFirstQVTable" class="QuickViewTable">
        HELLO
        </div>`

Comment: jQuery objects have a html() function, doesn't have anything such as innerHTML, use $('#iframeID').contents().find('#yourdivID').html('your value');

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$("#FrameProjectQuickView").contents().find("your div id or class").text("You text here");
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I have tried this but still not working ... whats the main reason  unable to find it ...

Comment: Try with different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

$('#ContentPlaceHolderRight_FrameProjectQuickView').parent().siblings('.FrameProjectQuickView').find('#DivFirstQ‌​VTable').html("PRINT SOME TEXT");

Comment: I did

`alert($('#ContentPlaceHolderRight_FrameProjectQuickView').parent().siblings('#DivFirstQ‌​VTable'));
    
    $('#ContentPlaceHolderRight_FrameProjectQuickView').parent().siblings('#DivFirstQ‌​VTable').html("PRINT SOME TEXT");`

alert gives - Object
But No changes happened inside div.

Comment: I need to know how your iframe element and yourDiv element are positoned.

Comment: I want to send you screenshot, pls share your EMAIL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59913/discussion-between-viswanath-d-and-puneet-2696717).

Comment: Check it and let me know if you are able to.

Comment: Nops ... still No response